# $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)=E(X^2)$ for a real-valued random variable X?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$, where $X$ is a real-valued random variable on $\Omega$, where $(\Omega,F,P)$ is a probability space.

Then this should imply that 
$$
X\in L^2(\Omega,F,P)
$$
since $E(X^2)=E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$.

Am I right?

In fact, $X$ could be complex-valued, then $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$ means that $X$ is in the complex Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega,F,P)$, doesn't it?

**To sum it up:**

If $X$ is is real-valued, $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$ implies that $X$ is in the real Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega,F,P)$ since $E(X^2)=E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$.

If $X$ is complex-valued, $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$ implies that $X$ is in the complex valued Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega,F,P)$.

Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are your two statements different?

Since $X^2 = |X|^2$ if $X$ if real valued, the first one is obvious. Note also that the following holds:

$$X \in L^1 \iff |X| \in L^1$$

which may not be immediately clear, as one is tempted to think "well if I have some negative values that can cancel out the positve ones, $E[X]$ can exists even if $E[|X|]$ does not." which is wrong for the definition of $E[X]$; basically we require the integral of the positive and negative part to exists separately and then we add them up :-)

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. If $X$ is real-valued, then, since $X^2=\lvert X\rvert^2$, presupposing $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$ implies that $X\in L^2$.  - - If $X$ is complex-valued and we suppose again that $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$, then $X$ is in the complex Hilbert space $L^2$, since the condition to be in it is exactly that $E(\lvert X\rvert^2)<\infty$.

Comment: @M.Meyer Exactly :-)